# Exchange Automation Script

Tags: powershell, date, datetime, exchange-server

I'm trying to write a powershell script for Exchange that will find the amount of emails a specific mailbox has received within a 1 month time frame and email those object totals to specific individuals. So Far I've Got:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy
$time = Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss
$previousMonth = 

PS C:\> Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients:mailbox1.org -start "02/01/2017 00:00:00" -end "$date $time" -EventId "Receive" -ResultSize unlimited | Measure-Object
PS C:\> Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients:mailbox2.org -start "02/01/2017 00:00:00" -end "$date $time" -EventId "Receive" -ResultSize unlimited | Measure-Object
PS C:\> Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients:mailbox3.org -start "02/01/2017 00:00:00" -end "$date $time" -EventId "Receive" -ResultSize unlimited | Measure-Object
PS C:\> Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients:mailbox4.org -start "02/01/2017 00:00:00" -end "$date $time" -EventId "Receive" -ResultSize unlimited | Measure-Object
ps c:\> Send-MailMessage  -SmtpServer "server" -To "recipient email<recipient email>" -From "Monthly Mailbox Totals <email address>" -Subject "Monthly Mailbox Item Count"  -Body ""
```

What I'm having trouble with is this: I can't quite figure out how to calculate the date range for the -start input to get the 1st of the previous month from the current date and time, and secondly I'm stuck on how to get the totals from this formatted into the body of the email that is sent. I want this script to run on the first of every month if that helps at all.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated thank you in advance.

Comment: I see 2-3 separate questions here. You should try to limit yourself to just one. There are date methods your could use to get dates in the past and even keep your current formatting logic. You are not even saving the results from your tracking log requests. Are you also asking how to automate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.DateTime` has a function AddX (Days,Hours,Minutes etc.). With these you can specify an exact timeframe. Then you just add up the returned value from `Get-MessageTrackingLog` and send the contents of your variable away.

```
$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14) #Get the last 2 Weeks
$EndDate = Get-Date
$i = 0
$ += (Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients "RecipientA" -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate -EventId "Receive" -ResultSize unlimited | measure).Count
$ += (Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients "RecipientB" -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate -EventId "Receive" -ResultSize unlimited | measure).Count
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "server" -To "recipient" -From "sender" -Subject "Mailcount" -Body "Mail count for this month is $i"
```

If you need the flexibility to set timeframes yourself you can simply use the type accelerator to convert your datestring into `DateTime`

```
$StartDate = [DateTime]"3.10.17"
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! Using (Get-Date).AddDays(-14) is it able to be formatted? I need to have it MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss would it be 

(Get-Date).AddDays(-14) -Format  MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: You don't need to format it to use it in `Get-MessageTrackingLog`. It simply uses the current Date and Time and substracts 14 Days. If you want to format it for output purposes then you can do it like this: `(Get-Date).AddDays(-14).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")`